# Why rendered htmls are not equal in a test?

Tags: django, django-testing

I have the following view:

```
from reports_system.apps.reports.forms import UploadReportForm
from reports_system.apps.reports.models import Reports


class IndexReports(ListView):
    """"""

    model = Reports
    context_object_name = 'reports_list'
    template_name = 'excel_reports.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
         context = super(IndexReports, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         # Add additional context variables
         context['UploadReportForm'] = UploadReportForm
         return context
```

And this is my test:

```
class ReportsListPageTest(TestCase):

def test_reports_url_resolves_to_reports_list_view(self):
    found = resolve('/reports/')
    self.assertEqual(found.func.__name__, IndexReports.as_view().__name__)


def test_reports_list_page_returns_correct_html(self):
    response = self.client.get('/reports/')
    expected_html = render_to_string(
        'excel_reports.html', 
        {'UploadReportForm': UploadReportForm, 'reports_list': Reports.objects.all()}
        )
    self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
```

Error:

```
in test_reports_list_page_returns_correct_html
self.assertEqual(response.content.decode(), expected_html)
AssertionError: '\n\n[18671 chars]     <input type=\'hidden\' name=\'csrfmiddlew[10690 chars]l>\n' != '\n\n[18671 chars]     \n                                       [10593 chars]l>\n'
```

If I print `response.content.decode()` and `expected_html`, they look visually the same.
Why do I have this error?

Test works if it is rewritten with RequestFactory, however I would like to use a simpler code.

Comment: It's pretty hard to do exact matching of rendered HTML and that's not really a good domain to be examining in a unit test. Leave that for your integration testing and just check that the API parts are giving you the right values. Your HTML comparison there is just a string comparison so one space makes them "not the same".

Comment: What Two-Bit Alchemist said, plus I'm pretty sure this is an arguable dupe (at least in the concept of doing unit tests by trying to exactly match HTML is an antipattern), and plus note that there's a good chance that the CSRF middleware is messing things up (since I would expect this could change everytime you call it)

Comment: Yes, perhaps everything I need to test about this particular view is that (1) the correct template is used and (2) variables that are supposed to be there are actually there. Here how I did it:
`self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'excel_reports.html')`
`self.assertEqual(response.context['UploadReportForm'].__name__, UploadReportForm.__name__)`